# Acquiring the necessary background for research

Tags: research

I'm starting my mater's thesis in computer science. I'm interested in computational Origami (algorithms mainly); I've read a little about the subject and I'm worried because I lack some of the knowledge that I think is necessary to do research in that area. But still I'd like to start and want to ask: which is better an approach: learn the necessary background as I go and wheneve a necessity pops up or learn it first and then start. I have 4 to 5 months to finish my thesis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my experience, it is better to learn stuff as you need it. Otherwise, you don't have the motivation to *really* "get" it, and there is always the risk of getting lost in the forest of interesting stuff out there (that in the end is of no use). Be at the lookout for results that could help you (Google or citeseerx or ..., or even this site, are your friends).

Another piece of advise: Start writing right now. Editing your ramblings into something coherent later on is easy, sitting in front of a blank screen with writer's block when the deadline approaches is extremely painful. Write down what you do right now; if it works out it stays for later, if not it gets erased (and you don't get embarassed by your dumb attempts ;-). That way it doesn't happen to you that you *know* something is right, but don't remember why... and have to redo lots of work (happened to me!).

Make a short (3-4 line) summary of each paper or other reference that looks relevant, add it to your bibliography. Reading the stuff so you are able to extract what is relevant to you helps understanding the stuff, the summaries help in locating material later. And the collection of summaries will be your chapter on state of the art (after cleanup).

As a final comment, use LaTeX (it looks much nicer, has very good handling of bibliographies ;-), and perhaps [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) for figures (it is a bit hard to learn, but has C++-like syntax to manipulate points and define lines, and produces excelent results). Put the whole stuff under version control (my favorite is [git](http://www.git-scm.com), but use whatever you are confortable with). That  way you'll be able to have an up-to-date backup (preferrably on some other machine!), and go back if you *really* mess up (Murphy's lat assures us you will).

Comment: Upvote for the recommendation of git and LaTeX, but it's worth noting that both of those will require significant time to learn for the uninitiated.

Comment: True, but as a CS mayor they should have had their squirmishes with LaTeX and _some_ VCS.

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks! I know how to use git. I'm sure I can learn LaTeX along the way.

Comment: Be sure to subscribe to http://tex.stackexchange.com (that is how I became aware of this site ;-). Take a look at http://ctan.org, rummage around in the documentation section. The AMS packages are required for any serious math typing, check out the documentation (and read it carefully!). I also found the document  Mathmode.pdf (also on CTAN) useful. Check out http://newton.ex.ac.uk/tex, particularly the stuff on BibTeX under "Utilities".

Answer (score 4):

I agree that you will be more motivated for deep understanding once you have already begun working. At the same time, you want to make sure that you have covered enough background that you don't "reinvent the wheel". I suggest alternating your background reading and more focused work. Once you've started working, it will help focus your reading. Your reading may in turn spark new ideas for your work.

I find it helpful to read first for breadth, and then for depth. A good survey paper can save a lot of time here, but if not, I like to take a very brief look at a whole range of papers to determine what's important, then take a deeper look at the papers which have had the most impact or are most important to my particular interest. I read just the introductions of a few of the most recent papers. It helps orient me to what have been the seminal papers over time. Then I take a look at those papers. Going in historical order can help, since later papers build on earlier papers, but also be aware that later papers may refine or simplify earlier ideas as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all useful mentioned recomendations, I recommend you to find good "**survey paper**" in your area. It will help you to get the big picture of the research topics and some open and hot questions. They also contain the well known references.